# Python3 goto assignment as infinite while-loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver, goto

I am a python novice and did not understand how to assign a "[goto](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-is-there-no-goto)" label in python3/selenium. I understood that there are none, but how can I write my script so that it does not fail to execute the infinite while-loop (here written in pseudo code)?:

```
while True:
    for-loop1
        something happens

    for-loop2
        something else is happening

    for-loop3
        even more stuff happens

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:not(.disabled)>a[data-page='next']"))).click() # checks for other page
        print("There is another page.")
        time.sleep( 2 ) # wait to load
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No further page exists. Bye, bye!")
        break

driver.quit()
```

I get the following error message:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:not(.disabled)>a[data-page='next']"))).click() # checks for other page
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

**Edit:**

Problem solved with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li:not(.disabled)>a[data-page='next']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly you don't need to use a "goto" at all. You can solve it by using a simple while loop wrapped around your for loops.

```
while True:
    for things in loop1:
        do stuff

    for things in loop2:
        do more stuff

    if there_are_no_more_pages:
        break
```

Comment: Hi, Uisdean Chapped, thank you for your answer. The problem is that I do not know how many pages I have until I click on the next button. If there is not next button, the script would finish. So, I thought that I just have the two for-loops regardless the page count and then check whether I can click on next for another page on the website or not, but I do not know how to implement it. Any ideas?

Comment: @TilHund what if you add the next button if you have more pages and wait for user input? 
With that you are able execute the for loops regardless of your page count and break out of the loop when there are no more pages to show.

Comment: Hi Uisdean Chapped, I have tried your infinite while-loop now (updated the original post accordingly), but get an error exactly where I check for the existents for the "next" button: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:not(.disabled)>a[data-page='next']"))).click() # checks for other page
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: I'm out of my depths w.r.t. the WebDriver thingy, therefore, I can't really help you there. However, since _wait for element_to_be_clickable_ fails because of a time-out it might wait for a click which is not happening or it just can't load the element. 
But really, at this point I'm guessing, sorry.

Comment: No worries, I found the last problem myself, however, you helped me with my initial one which is to discover that you can do infinite loops. Thank you again!